# how to run .exe file with different credentials?

Tags: powershell, credentials

I have used the below code, but it gives me an error like "file not found".
If I remove the last `-Credential ($credentials)` part the code is working fine.

Can any one suggest a solution?

```
$username = "abcd"
$password = "dcab"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

Start-Process CopyApplication.exe -WorkingDirectory "G:\abcd\CopyApplication\CopyApplication\bin\Debug" -Credential ($credentials)
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: is G a network drive? Mapping drive is Windows is user-specific, so it would explain the error. Plus: is CopyApplication in a system wide path? If not, try to run it with full path rather than depend on PATH variable.

Comment: G is not a network drive and it is a hard disk drive..

Comment: Is it possible to run with other credentials

Comment: In principle your code should work. Did you try starting `CopyApplication.exe` with its full path?

Comment: sorry Ansgar,
I didn't get you..

the full path is G:\abcd\CopyApplication\CopyApplication\bin\Debug\CopyApplication.exe only and it is working on a double click..

so no problem in running .exe..
more over that .exe is working with abcd user, so no problem in executing that with that particular  user account...

but still that power shell script is not working ...

Comment: the exact error is 
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot
find the file specified.
At
G:\abcd\CopyApplication\CopyApplication\bin\Debug\psfile.ps1:9
char:1
+ Start-Process CopyApplication.exe  -WorkingDirectory
"G:\abcd\Copy ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOp
   erationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
   ommands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: Are you sure your `$username` has enough permissions to read the `G:\abcd\CopyApplication\CopyApplication\bin` folder? When you try to access something 2+ levels below where read permissions end, you get `FileNotFound` instead of `AccessDenied`.

Comment: yes Alexander,
those credentials have enough permissions to run the .exe and open that folder.

Actually that is an windows presentation form application (.exe)
Will that be a problem..???@AlexanderObersht